# Remove name under space for signature in Latex scrlttr2

Tags: latex

How is it possible to remove my name under the space that is used for my signature.
I tried to leave the komavar "fromname" empty, that way I achived my aim but then also the name in my adress dissapear obviously. Any hints? Thanks.

Some minimal code

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}


\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street 1\\01234 MyCountry}
\setkomavar{place}{City}

\begin{letter}{Mr X\\
X Street 1\\
X town
}

\opening{Dear Mr X,}

foo bar

\closing{Yours My Name}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

What I want is to remove the words "My Name" at the end of the letter.

Comment: Probably need to change some code somewhere.  (A more detailed answer would require at least *some* details in the question.)

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `signature` variable to empty:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}


\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street 1\\01234 MyCountry}
\setkomavar{place}{City}

\setkomavar{signature}{}


\begin{letter}{Mr X\\
X Street 1\\
X town
}

\opening{Dear Mr X,}

foo bar

\closing{Yours My Name}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```